# I have what seems to be a type of markup from git scattered intermittently around my code

Tags: git, github, titanium

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
function patients($count = 20,$offset=0) { 
//unmodified code here
}
>>>>>>> 1f7cf457993ef185a960744695e79229b2acc055
```

These are scattered around my code, having been inserted by the github client or Titanium studio. I am completely at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git` is telling you that you have conflicts. Resolve them: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge